# Meteor / NodeJS run own code before migration start (Meteor startup)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor

is there a possibility to execute own code inside a Meteor / Node application before the migrations run?
I know about `Meteor.startup` but this code runs after the DB Migrations afaik.

Edit: The migrations package i use `idmontie:migrations@1.0.3`

Comment: which migrations package do you use?

Comment: @ChristianFritz `idmontie:migrations@1.0.3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [migration package you use](https://atmospherejs.com/idmontie/migrations) doesn't seem to support that. If, however, you are able to switch to the more common [percolate:migrations](https://atmospherejs.com/percolate/migrations) then you can fully control when the migration happens, because you actually need to call it explicitly, e.g.,

```js
Meteor.startup(() => {
  /* the code you want to run first here.. */
  Migrations.migrateTo('latest');
});
```

In the past, I've even done things like this, where I was running some code between migrations to certain versions:

```js
Meteor.startup(() => {
  /* some code to run before ... */
  Migrations.migrateTo(3);
  /* some code to run in between... */
  Migrations.migrateTo(5);
});
```

Comment: Do you know if there's an option to skip a certain version from the migrations or do i have to edit the migrations control entry in the mongo by myself?

Comment: In theory you can just write into the only document in the `db.migrations` collection, and manually increase the version you claim to be on there. This would effectively skip a migration. But the whole point of migrations is usually that no step should be skipped, so this doesn't seem like a good idea where it can be avoided.

Comment: I agree with you, problem is, i need to find a way, to not execute the migrations from the old package when updating an existing system while on a new system i want to do all mirations.

Comment: ah, yes, in that case just set the version number in the db on the existing systems to be the version that the old package already migrated to.